# How to see codes in full width in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, visual-studio-code

I want to use full viewport while coding in VS Code. But the lines are not expanding when i expand my VS Code window.
Any Fix ?

[image]

Comment: Just try to add plugins such as Prettier or Beautify and select all document and just format the document. Or alternatively you can use shortcut Shift+Alt+F. In case you have broken the line or provide extralines with no content it will leave that as it is and beautify everything.

Comment: You are using prettier, and prettier writes from new line after 80 characters in each line by default. You can change settings in "Prettier: Print Width" field.

Comment: you have no long lines, type long lines or remove a formatter or change the settings of the formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The correct configuration to use:

---

In order to configure V.S. Code so that the lines of code in
your editor will only wrap at the end of the view port, and
never before, you need to assign the correct value to the
setting: **`editor.wordWrap`**

There are 4 different values that can be assigned to the
**`editor.wordWrap`** setting. There is one that I believe
is exactly what you are asking for, however; 2 of the other
three could work too, so I will list them all, and suggest
the one I think will work best for you. The following are
the only "out-of-the-box" line-wrapping configurations that
VSCode supports, and they are as follows:

---

##### 01|   `"editor.wordWrap": "off"`_

— Assigning *`off`* to the *`wordWrap` setting* will make it
so that your editors lines will never auto-wrap. The only
way a line will ever be moved to the next line is if you add
a line break — by pressing the **`[ENTER]`** key. — and
proceed to continue typeing text on the next line. This way
could work for you, because you get 100% control over when
the lines break.

---

##### 02|   *`"editor.wordWrap": "on"`*

- Assigning *`on`* to the `editor.wordWrap` setting makes it
  so that that the lines of code in your editor will wrap
  exactly where the viewport ends. No matter how big, or how
  small the editor's viewport width is, the lines always
  extend the entirety of the viewport, and never before.

**NOTE:** `"on"` *sounds to me like what you were asking for*
*in your question*

---

##### 03|   *`"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn"`*

- When you assign ***`wordWrapColumn`*   —to—   *`"editor.wordWrap"`*** the lines of code inside your editors view-port will wrap at what ever you set the setting *`editor.wordWrapColumn`* to. To be more specific, I'll give you an example.

###### if you configure *`wordWrapColumn`* so that it looks like the code-snippet below:

##### *`"editor.wordWrapColumn": 80`*

###### ...then your lines will all wrap at 80.

- This is by far the most popular configuration, as it is frequently coupled with 3rd party formatters, and linters, such as ESLint & Prettier. Prettier's `printWidth` setting, coupled with *`"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn"`*, is an extremely reliable and consistent configuration.

---

##### 4| *`"editor.wordWrap": "bounded"`*

— Last is *`"bounded"`*, bounded is a mix between on, and print width. In a nutshell, lines will wrap if either of two conditions are true.
- First lines will wrap at what ever *`"editor.wordWrapColumn"`* is set to, just like the configuration example #3.
- Secondly, lines will wrap at the end of the view port.
To reiterate through what I just typed, lines wrap at _`"editor.wordWrapColumn"`'_s value, unless the view-port is smaller than the value of *`"editor.wordWrapColumn"`*, in that case lines wrap at the view-port.

---

###### *That's all...*

Comment: PrintWidth option worked for me. I changed the value from 80 to 100 and the line breaking problem was gone. thanks :)

Comment: @Sayak-dutta no problem bud. Can you do me one favor though, and mark this answer as being correct, so when people search for it they see that this answer solved your problem. Also, so we both get our points :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any extension in you VS code such as Beautify or Prettier. Or if you want to format the document you can simply use shortcut Shift+Alt+F.

If you want to merge multiline code into single.Follow the steps

1.Select all line you want to merge in single.

2.Press F1 and search for join lines.

3.Select join lines and press enter.

You can also create a keyboard shortcut for this command `editor.action.joinLines`

Answer (score -1):

`"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true`

Adding this setting to your settings.json will enable zooming in when holding `CTRL` and scrolling. After you save settings.json with this setting, you can hold the ctrl key and scroll with your mouse or trackpad to zoom in which will make your code cover the full screen. If you want more focus, you can enter **Zen Mode**. It is a nice feature built into Visual Studio Code, which helps you to focus more on your code than the activity bar or other files. You can toggle zen mode with shortcut keys `CTRL + K Z`, Command palette, or View menu.